# Trouble loading SVGs in Angular project on Apache

Tags: apache, angular, .htaccess, svg

I've put my first Angular project live, serving on Apache. I found an htaccess to use somewhere (don't remember where now...)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Unfortunately, I suck with htaccess files. With this one, I can access any Angular routes, as expected, however, all my SVG files come up 403:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /assets/cross.svg on this server.
Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
```

The files are owned by the correct group, and are all set to 664, as are all my files, so I can't figure out why CSS and JS files load, but SVGs 403.

I'd love some advice/tutelage on where I've gone wrong.

As requested, from my conf, here is the directory rules:

```
<Directory /var/www/opweekends.api/public/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: What are your directory rules for Apache?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly @ThinkingMedia, I've added my directory code from my conf above.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the rewrite rules from CakePHP. It's simple and has always worked for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/master/webroot/.htaccess

> Note: There is a space after the ^ character. Not sure if the space is required or not.

If you continue to get the same error, then it's not a rewrite problem.

Comment: I'll try it out, though isn't that just the same thing, only ignoring if you hit a directory directly and no base set?

Comment: That's why I think this might not be a rewrite problem. To remove it as a cause let's try what has always worked for me. ;)

Comment: Yah, same here; just wanted to make sure. Changing the htaccess didn't fix it, and I don't know how to debug from here :/

Comment: Can you confirm that Angular is trying to load the SVG files from the server, and is not expecting WebPack to provide them as a bundled asset. Check the browser network panel and verify there is a GET request for each SVG file.

Comment: Yah, there's an asset request for each SVG. It's definitely something on the server end.

Comment: As a test can you run `sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/opweekends.api/public` just to verify it's not a file permission problem.

Comment: Wow! This is insane. If you copy one of the SVG files to the web root. Can you access it manually via the browser address bar?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150641/discussion-between-rhovisions-and-thinkingmedia).